# Is there a way to build a time series that has a known autocorrelation function?

Tags: r, time-series, autocorrelation

Is there a way to build a time series that has a known autocorrelation function? For example a time series that has the following ACF $e^t\cos t$.

Comment: That's not a valid ACF, so is your question about how to (a) create a *model* for a time series with a given (valid) ACF; (b) how to create on *instance* of a time series from such a model; (c) how to create an instance whose *empirical* ACF is the one you stipulate; or (d) how to identify a valid ACF?

Comment: Just take some data with a known period, maybe?

Comment: That would cause the ACF to be periodic and so wouldn't work otherwise.  Even supposing the OP were asking about $e^{-t}\cos(t)$ this wouldn't work, because that's not a (Real) periodic function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, take a look at [Yule-Walker](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Esteele/Courses/956/ResourceDetails/YWSourceFiles/YW-Eshel.pdf) as an example. It [may not be the best way](http://stat.wharton.upenn.edu/%7Esteele/Courses/956/Resource/YWSourceFiles/WhyNotToUseYW.pdf), but gives you an idea. Section 2.5 has the equation:
$$\bf\hat\Phi=R^{-1}r$$
where $\bf r,R$ - are a ACF and the matrix constructed from ACF; and $\bf\Phi$ are lag coefficients of AR Tim-series.